# Android Dynamic RelativeLayout AddRules(); not working as expected

Tags: android, android-layout, android-service, android-relativelayout

I am trying to show some views dynamically in a relative layout from a service. Basically, I am trying to get a `TextView` to show up right of an `ImageView`, like this:

```
ImageView TextView
```

What I actually get is:

```
TextView                        ImageView
```

(With that empty space. )

My variables:

```
private WindowManager windowManager;
private ImageView myImage;
private TextView  myText;
private RelativeLayout myRelativeLayout;
private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imageParams;
private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textParams;
private WindowManager.LayoutParams relativeLayoutParams;
```

---

The service's onCreate method:

```
    windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    myImage= new ImageView(this);
    myImage.setId(R.id.myImage);

    myText= new TextView(this);
    myText.setId(R.id.myText);

    myRelativeLayout= new RelativeLayout(this);
    myRelativeLayout.setId(R.id.myRelativeLayout);


    final WindowManager.LayoutParams windowManagerParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    textParams= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );

    imageParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );

    relativeLayoutParams= new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
    );

   imageParams.addRule(
   RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT | 
   RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, myRelativeLayout.getId()); 
   //Tried without getId(),too
  //If I omit ALIGN_PARENT_TOP here, the views are shown on top of each other

   textParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, myImage.getId());

    windowManager.addView(myRelativeLayout, layoutParams);
    myRelativeLayout.addView(myImage, imageParams);
    myRelativeLayout.addView(myText, textParams); 

    // This does not appear to have any significance. 
    windowManager.updateViewLayout(myRelativeLayout, layoutParams);
```

---

The view ids are assined in an XML file. Trying to get it to run on API 14. The final puzzle will have plenty more views so I'd much rather stick to a relative layout.

I have read most anything I could find on the subject, but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I have tried setting gravity properties as well, but no luck. I will also need to handle click events later on. I have tried inflating the layout from an XML, and it works, but, as far as I understand, I can't access the views later on with this method.

Comment: What is your quoteWindow....?

Comment: tried [this](http://www.xmltojava.com/) ?

Comment: Interesting tool, but it produces pretty much the same code I already have.

Answer (score 0):

LayoutInflater is right option and you can reach views as they are in windowManager and your service is not destroyed!

Answer (score 0):

You should do like below,

```
    windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    myImage= new ImageView(this);
    myImage.setId(R.id.myImage);

    myText= new TextView(this);
    myText.setId(R.id.myText);

    myRelativeLayout= new RelativeLayout(this);
    myRelativeLayout.setId(R.id.myRelativeLayout);


    final WindowManager.LayoutParams windowManagerParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    textParams= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );

    imageParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );

    relativeLayoutParams= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
    );

   imageParams.addRule(
   RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);//RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP 
   imageParams.addRule(
   RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
   //Tried without getId(),too
  //If I omit ALIGN_PARENT_TOP here, the views are shown on top of each other
   textParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, myImage.getId());
   textParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

    windowManager.addView(myRelativeLayout, layoutParams);
    myRelativeLayout.addView(myImage, imageParams);
    myRelativeLayout.addView(myText, textParams); 

    // This does not appear to have any significance. 
    windowManager.updateViewLayout(myRelativeLayout, layoutParams);
```

Comment: Setting margins for textParams and/or imageParams had no effect. Moving ALIGN_PARENT_TOP to a new addRule() produces the same result as removing it: the text is shown over the image. I hope I did not miss any other changes.